# how to insert full name in mysql database using servlet ? for eg - viraj sharma

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

My code is

```
 @Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
   PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
   try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/patient", "root", "");
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into userdetails(userType) VALUES(?)");
    ps.setString(1, req.getParameter("userType"));

    int b = ps.executeUpdate();
    if (b > 0)
     out.print("succes");
    else
     out.print("fail");
   }
```

when I run this program it only inserts first-name of full name i.e `viraj`
and I want to store `viraj Sharma`.

Comment: `req.getParameter("userType")` appears to contain the value `viraj` (not `viraj Sharma`).  Debug or log the value, and check the source of the value.  Also, if "userType" represents a full name, then consider renaming the parameter to something like "fullName".

Comment: Please post your jsp page from where you are getting data